# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error u

Tags: http, struts2, glassfish, redirect

Fact:

I am requesting root application on my browser `http://localhost:8080/myapp` and my browser throws this error: `Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): many redirects`.

Environment:

I'm using Java 6, Glassfish 2.1, Struts2, Spring and Hibernate.

Check:

Then I look into web.xml and in welcome-list-files I have this:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

So, let's check `index.jsp` and there is this redirection:

```
...
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=<%=request.getContextPath()%>/portal/home.do">
...
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/img/icono.png" />
</head>
...
```

Then we can go to `struts.xml` and we can see this chunk:

```
...
<package name="portal-action" extends="portal-base" namespace="/portal">
    <action name="home" method="home" class="beginAction">
        <result type="tiles">begin.home</result>
    </action>
...
```

Let's check `beginAction` class:

```
...
public String home(){
    return SUCCESS;
}
...
```

And we can check `tiles.xml`:

```
...
<definition name="begin.welcome" extends=".baseHome">
    <put-attribute name="working.region" value="/jsp/common/welcome.jsp" />
</definition>
...
```

And finally we can view entire `welcome.jsp` file which only contains:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<br />
```

That's all!

Do you have some idea about this issue?

Answer (score 6):

Just to state the obvious, it looks like your app is caught in a redirect loop. Looking at your configuration, I have no idea what the issue could be. I would try opening up a network monitor like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), or the "Network" tab in Chrome's developer tools and look at the response headers to see where it is trying to redirect you to ... that might help reveal what is going wrong here.

Comment: Thank very much. I'm testing these tools. Any result I will post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I had this case in SharePoint 2013  REST API when calling /_api/web/lists/....

it returned no rows and just shows this error

at error WFE error logs there were some errors with below details

```
System.ServiceModel 4.0.0.0
3
WebHost
Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/_vti_bin/cellstorage.https.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Security settings for this service 
require  'Anonymous' Authentication but it is not enabled** for the IIS application that hosts this service..
```

it is said in the error and i remembered that we disabled **'Anonymous' Authentication** for some reason last night in the SharePoint 8 via IIS

re-enabling 'Anonymous' Authentication in IIS for Sharepoint app on port 80  fixed the problem